# Why is 3 behaving differently from int(3)?

Tags: python

Consider this:

```
>>> 3.__hash__()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    3.__hash__()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And this:

```
>>> int(3).__hash__()
3
```

But for what I can see, `3` and `int(3)` are the same thing. Same `id()`, same `dir()`, same `hash()`...

So what is happening here ?

Comment: Because `3.` is a floating point number, so `3._` is not valid syntax. Use `(3).__hash__()`, for example.

Comment: Compare `type(3.)` and `type(3)` :-)

Comment: thank you. now that you say it, it seems quite obvious. (Just tested with `(3)`, works too). But isn't that a bit silly that `.` is used for both decimal separation and function call?

Comment: @njzk2: how often do you need to call a method on an integer literal?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I was trying to figure out if and then why there is no `__eq__` on ints, and then wondering why there would be a `__hash__`

Comment: @njzk2: in Python 2, [`__cmp__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__) is provided instead. In Python 3, `int.__eq__` does exist.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: sorry, going totally off-topic, but then, `__cmp__` returns 0, so shouldn't there be some testing like `(3).__cmp__(3) == 0` to test for equality ? (I guess not as that would form a loop).

Comment: @njzk2: Not in C code, it doesn't. The `__cmp__` **implementation** looks at C values.

Comment: ok thanks. quite clearer.